# Importing SSL Certificate into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, ssl-certificate

How do you import an SSL certificate created by java into a project in Eclipse?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Probably you want to import a "fake" SSL cert in JRE's trustcacerts for avoiding not-a-valid-certificate issues. Isn't it?

As Jon said, you can do the job with [keytool](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html):

```
keytool
    -import
    -alias <provide_an_alias>
    -file <certificate_file>
    -keystore <your_path_to_jre>/lib/security/cacerts
```

Use "changeit" as the default password when asked ([thanks Brian Clozel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684081/importing-ssl-certificate-into-eclipse#comment2400032_685036)). Ensure to use this runtime at your server or launch configuration.

Comment: Worked for me.
FYI, the default password associated with your keystore is "changeit"

Comment: When I enter `java keytool` in cmd.exe, I get "*Error: Could not find or load main class keytool*". Where should we be entering these commands?

Comment: Instead of "-keystore <your_path_to_jre>/lib/security/cacerts", you can just put "-cacerts" as a shortcut.  (I believe this shortcut is a recent addition to the tool and it might not work in older versions of Java.)

Comment: Finally i did it---- Eclipse holds it's own jre in c:/users/..... folder we have to search cacerts in that folder or find what jre eclipse is using and import to that then it works. I got cacerts in "C:\Users\username\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.3.v20220515-1416\jre\lib\security"

Answer (score 53):

In case you have the certificate already in your Windows' certificate store (this is common in corporate/company deployments with MITM certificates), you can also use the following steps (with help from [another Stackoverflow answer with more detailed explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011158/12932497)):

1. Locate the `eclipse.ini` file in your Eclipse installation and open it
2. Below the line `-vmargs`, add the following lines, then save the file:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

3. Restart eclipse.

Comment: Tested on Eclipse 4.10@ Windows 10 64bit  PC - running in corporate LAN. Worked like a charm !

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I'm on a corporate LAN, Win10 64-bit, eclipse   Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0). Thanks!

Comment: If work behind corporate proxy this is the solution

Comment: THIS SOLUTION solved my problem of installing Eclipse Plugins from Marketplace that have a Update Site published under https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ !!!

Comment: @CristianoCostantini you are a savior ! Thank you

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. It worked

Comment: What do these two lines mean?

Comment: @th1rdey3: `-D` means setting a JVM property. The meaning of the JVM properties is documented in the link.

Comment: The lines enable the KNIME Analytics Platform (based on Eclipse) to get updates and extensions from our very restrictive enterprise's VPN.

Answer (score 10):

There's a better tool for the job.

[KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/index.html)

When you run (run as administrator in windows in order to save changes to system, sudo in linux, etc.) the application (it has installers for win/mac/linux) there's a built-in function to edit the system's cacerts file:

File -> Open Special -> Open CA Certificates

[image: Open CA Certificates]

**EITHER** you already have the certificate file and you can go to:

Tools -> Import Trusted Certificate

**OR** you need to download the certificate from the server; go to:

Examine -> Examine SSL

[image: Examine menu]

[image: Examine SSL]

From there type in the hostname and click ok.  It will pop up a window showing the certificate details.  At the bottom of that window there's an "Import" button that will allow you to directly import it into the cacerts.

[image: Certificate Details for SSL Connection]

Make sure you save and close cacerts, and restart your eclipse/application for the settings to take effect.

Comment: Quite an interesting/useful tool, +1.

Comment: this answer should get more votes :)

Comment: If you have scoop (and if not you should) just install it with `scoop install keystore-explorer`

Comment: It's also available from winget:

winget search KeyStoreExplorer
Name              Id                         Version Source
------------------------------------------------------------
KeyStore Explorer KaiKramer.KeyStoreExplorer 5.5.3   winget

Answer (score 5):

### Mac

1. Open **Keychain Access.app** (Shortcut: press Command + Spacebar and type Keychain)
2. Search the desired certificate file (e.g. `example.cer`) and right-click ➡️ Select **Export...** ➡️ Save it to some location e.g. `Desktop`.
3. Follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66889979/10819573) to import it to your Java certificate store. The important commands are:

```
cd $JAVA_HOME/lib/security
sudo cp cacerts cacerts.bak
sudo keytool -importcert -alias youralias -file ~/Desktop/example.cer -keystore cacerts
```

The default password of the keystore is: `changeit`.

4. Assuming, `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security` points to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security` in your system, add the following lines in the `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

**Note:** If you are using STS, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68775329/10819573) to locate the `.ini` file.

5. Restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

We need to import a certificate means we need to use :

```
keytool 
 -importcert 
 -file <certificate_location> 
 -keystore <jre_location\lib\security\cacerts> 
 -alias "<cert_name>"
```

It will ask for a password. Type the password as `changeit`

```
Type Password : changeit
```

finally it will ask need to add {yes/no} :

type yes.

Note: Don't give blank space in location path

Comment: At the risk of asking a silly question, is the keytool utility available on a Windows install of Eclipse? If so, where?
Thanks. EDIT: Found it. For others' benefit, it's in the Java install, e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin

Comment: it will helpful when working in server side applications like ESB,JBoss,etc. and HTTPS service client call

Answer (score 1):

If you have default Java setup and have provided Java classpath, then you must be using Java Truststore for SSL certificates.

For this you can follow below steps to import certificates into Trust store:

1. Navigate to the JRE\bin folder of your Java setup
   Ideally the path should be:

> user\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin

2. You will be able to find Keytool in the bin folder(which will be used to run the commands):

[Path to locate Keytool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGams.jpg)

3. Now once you are on this path, open the path in your CMD prompt:

[Bin folder in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtQOI.jpg)

4. Now you will be able to find default Trust store of Java at below path:
   Path-

> user\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin

[Path to Java default Trust store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcMhV.jpg)

5. Now you can run below command to see contents of this Trust store:

   keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib\security\cacerts"

Note: If your path to Trust store has spaces in it, then you need to use double quotes for the path. Else you can provide path like below:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Temp\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib\security\cacerts
```

Now just provide password to Trust Store(Default password is: changeit):
[Accessing Trust store using Keytool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReNH1.jpg)

6. You can now as per your need add any certificate to the Trust store:

   JRE_HOME/bin/keytool  -import  -trustcacerts
                            -alias certAlias  -file certFile
                            -keystore trustStoreFile

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create the certificate and import it into the default keystore using keytool.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your application, but it should then be able to use that certificate.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo  keytool -import  -file /Users/balaji-pt2176/Desktop/Apple\ Worldwide\ Developer\ Relations\ Certification\ Authority.cer  -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

in mac