# "PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to get tweets using twitter4j library for my java project which uses under the covers `java.net.HttpURLConnection` (as can be seen in stack trace). On my first run I got an error about certificate `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException` and `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException`. Then I added twitter certificate by:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\security>keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file PathToCert -alias ca_alias -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

But without success. Here is the procedure to get tweets:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("myConsumerKey")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("myConsumerSecret")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("myAccessToken")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("myAccessTokenSecret");
    
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    
    try {
        Query query = new Query("iphone");
        QueryResult result;
        result = twitter.search(query);
        System.out.println("Total amount of tweets: " + result.getTweets().size());
        List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        
        for (Status tweet : tweets) {
            System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " : " + tweet.getText());
        }
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
    }
```

And here is the error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=d35baff5 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1446302e
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[d35baff5-1446302e 43208640-747fd158 43208640-747fd158 43208640-747fd158], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.5}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:81)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1929)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:306)
    at jku.cc.servlets.TweetsAnalyzer.main(TweetsAnalyzer.java:38)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:34)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:141)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
Failed to search tweets: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Hello Please check below URL. I am sure these will help you. http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210 https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Unable+to+Connect+to+SSL+Services+due+to+PKIX+Path+Building+Failed+sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException. You have to add your ssl certificate into java truststore certificate (Path: jre/lib/security/cacerts).

Comment: Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40417523/1802348) answer for solution plus do confirm you are packaging your software as bundled jre ? if yes then copy your cacerts file form system and replace that packaged jre cacerts file.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9210661/4741746 may be this is your answer

Comment: I just used this java code and for https don't forget to specify the port as 443.
Java code at 
https://github.com/escline/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java

It will take your CACERTS file and will add all those plus the current cert for the URL you give as input.
In my case I hardcoded the values to 
host="mywebservice.uat.xyz.com";
port=443;
passphrase="changeit".toCharArray();

Then the program creates a new file called "jssecacerts" which will have everything. Rename this to "cacerts" and use this . You will be all set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

Comment: I just replace HTTPS to HTTP and it works. Maybe my comment will be useful for someone

Comment: When running `mvn` adding this argument fixed it for me because it wasn't using the default java trust store in JAVA_HOME for some reason: `-"Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore"="C:\path\to\your\cacerts"`

Answer (score 1135, accepted):

1. Go to URL in your browser:

- firefox -  click on HTTPS certificate chain (the lock icon right next to URL address). Click `"more info" > "security" > "show certificate" > "details" > "export.."`. Pickup the name and choose file type example.cer
- chrome - click on site icon left to address in address bar, select "Certificate" -> "Details" -> "Export" and save in format "Der-encoded binary, single certificate".

2. Now you have file with keystore and you have to add it to your JVM. Determine location of cacerts files, eg.
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\security\cacerts.`
3. Next import the `example.cer` file into cacerts in command line (may need administrator command prompt):

`keytool -import -alias example -keystore  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\security\cacerts" -file example.cer`

You will be asked for password which default is `changeit`

Restart your JVM/PC.

source:
http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html

Comment: I had to put the path in quotes and also save it as Base64 instead of DER

Comment: wow..its worked like a magic
by the way in chrome you just click the lock icon on left address bar, and then click _details_

plus there is no restart needed

Comment: On Mac OS X 10.11, jdk8, restart dosen't  needed in fact.

Comment: since java is not a  daemon and runs on demand, how to restart jvm?

Comment: Is the restart really necessary?  If so that's bollocks.

Comment: Worked fine. Just had to add quotes around the cert file path as @TheodoreK. mentioned

Comment: Note that instructions should be repeated for all certificates in the chain. Also certificate's `alias` name in command line should be unique.

Comment: Is there any workaround if I do not have write permissions to Program Files?

Comment: Even though I'm using a different browser and OS, this gave me the successful clue I needed - or reminded me of what I knew once, as certificate issues come up only once in a blue moon. The essential datum is: `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Comment: And it's here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980364/how-do-i-find-out-what-keystore-my-jvm-is-using

Comment: If your home is a JDK, make sure to specify that the jre lies within that:keytool -import -alias example -keystore  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file example.cer

Comment: For anyone getting an "access denied" error, make sure you're running command prompt as an administrator.

Comment: For us it was necessary to import the certificate to the file $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts as well.

Comment: Hi all, I'm facing the same issue. I've implemented the provided answer but still getting the same ssl excepton; also can you please tell me what to do with generated keystore file?

Comment: in my case it was .net certificate

Comment: Works like a charm. I added the .crt file exported from Firefox.

Comment: Wooowww finally I got the solution, i was trying the same solution from so many days in MAC and it was not working. The reason was the certificate was by default getting saved with .crt extension and which was not getting recognized. I saved the certificate with .cer extension and followed the same steps and tested using SSLPoke Class mentioned in below URL
https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html

Comment: fyi https://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/ is an awesome java utility to manage the java keystore, do export/import of CertSignRequests etc.

Comment: SSL(x.509) is about 'chain-of-trust'. So preferably one should add the 'certificate of the issuer' to the trust store, not the website certificate itself.

Comment: I got this error Certificate for <ipaddress> doesn't match common name of the certificate subject: hybris

Comment: Restarting the Virtual Machine (ec2) was the major factor in getting this solution to work for me. Thanks!

Comment: It works for me but when I try to update Android studio, it fails because of a conflict of cacerts. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: for url is this just any random url?

Comment: Its not working for me. Tried it from Android Studio and still getting the same

Comment: Our companie's IT has it's own root certificate so I had to import this. Worked for AdoptOpenJDK.

Comment: Worked like Charm - use double quotes for space related exception.

Comment: I tried to use with -alias option but was getting the error as "Illegal option:  alias". So had to remove the -alias option and it worked perfect.                                        keytool -import -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241\lib\security\cacerts" -file test-cert.cer

Comment: Took a few extra steps on a Macbook, but this worked!

Comment: I am still facing the issue. I have uploaded(imported) the cert from the site [link](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)  in my cacerts file in jre and jdk both. I have verified by the serial number in cacert file and they are imported successfully. Any further suggestions ?

Comment: Worked as advertised.  Now if I could only put back in the hairs I pulled out....

Comment: to run keytool command remember to run it from  cd %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: hmm I did this but now I'm getting "Certificate for <my-ec2-id.compute-1.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []". Any ideas?

Comment: I have added the required certificates and also restarted my system after that but still I am getting same error in my  IDE. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do I save the example.cer ?

Comment: Hi, I am having same issues with Eclipse Marketplace (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4) when I try to access it through Eclipse > Help > Eclipse Marketplace menu.  When you say "In your browser, go to URL..." to export certificate, which URL  are you referring to?  I tried from this eclipse market place URL and although I exported and added certificate successfully following your explanation, it did not fix my issue.  Thank you

Comment: For java jdk11, there is no jre.  How to run the above keytool command in case of jdk11?

Comment: How do we acheive the same for local jenkins set up? Because unable to get .cert format and only able to get .p12, .jks and when we bind that it throws error like "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate"

Comment: I did all that but still getting the error in STS.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531872/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-request - For reference. If someone could help.

Comment: Had this problem related to Maven repository at: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/  Blows my mind because our internal network was generating a self-signed cert that I had to export (using web browser) and then import using these instructions.  Couldn't have gotten through it without these instructions & I'm amazed I was even able to work through it considering how cryptic the error info from Maven the internal network error was.  Thanks again. 

Comment: Did not work for me.. the bottom answer did! Clearly, I am doing something screwy! meh!

Comment: Note to me: RTFM, "... You will be asked for password which default is `changeit`...".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997148/10183099 has the complete details and helped me when this answer did not.

Comment: When he say "Go to URL in your browser", what url is it?

Comment: i dont have admin access what should i do?

Comment: This worked for Mac as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 126):

After many hours trying to build cert files to get my Java 6 installation working with the new twitter cert's, I finally stumbled onto an incredibly simple solution buried in a comment in one of the message boards. Just copy the cacerts file from a Java 7 installation and overwrite the one in your Java 6 installation. Probably best to make a backup of the cacerts file first, but then you just copy the new one in and BOOM! it just works.

Note that I actually copied a Windows cacerts file onto a Linux installation and it worked just fine.

The file is located in `jre/lib/security/cacerts` in both the old and new Java jdk installations.

Hope this saves someone else hours of aggravation.

Comment: I am trying to access an ssl server with a self-signed certificate, tried adding it's certificate using keytool, but no luck, any suggestions?

Comment: Glad it worked.. But do you know what was the root cause. what made it to fail with java 6 certs.. and how does the java 7 certs fixed the problem

Comment: This did it, although I went from icedtea 1.6 to oracle 1.7. :)

Comment: Also consider this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439905/is-the-cacerts-file-missing-in-ubuntu-15-10-and-openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: For those who like me sometimes miss the obvious -- make sure you are going into `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib`, not `$JAVA_HOME/lib` -- I spent a bit of time missing that detail.

Comment: @Vishwanathgowdak The root cause likely is just that the newer JRE came with newer certificates built-in, which did not exist at the time the older version was released.

Answer (score 110):

MY UI approach:

1. Download keystore explorer from [here](https://keystore-explorer.org/)
2. Open $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
3. enter PW: changeit (Can be changeme on Mac)
4. Import your .crt file

CMD-Line:

1. `keytool -importcert -file jetty.crt -alias jetty -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`
2. enter PW: `changeit` (Can be changeme on Mac)

Comment: On mac, with CMD-Line, should use sudo to run the command.                   # sudo keytool -importcert -file jetty.crt -alias jetty -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Comment: On Windows, the command wich works: `keytool  -importcert -file dinardap_cert.cer –alias dinardap –keystore “%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts”`

Comment: where to get the cert file from? I can't tell which URL to go to. https://www.jetty.com ?

Comment: I've get my cert by exporting it from web browser, context action on padlock

Comment: This seems much simpler than working from command line.

Comment: "Enter keystore password" ...?

Comment: Thanks this worked for me as well. But I had to browse the endpoint from within company network to download the cert chain. On my PC I have ESET installed and it didn't show me the full cert path and instead root path was ESET itself somehow.

Comment: Worked for me in ubuntu, using java 11 installed with sdkman

Comment: @FlipNovid password is "changeit" It is too late I know, but anyone else may need that.

Answer (score 73):

### 1. Check the certificate

Try to load the target URL in browser and view the site's certificate (usually it's accessible by the icon with the lock sign. It's on the left or right side of the browser's address bar) whether it's expired or untrusted by other reason.

### 2. Install latest versions of JRE and JDK

New versions usually come with the updated set of the trusted certificates.

Also if it's possible, uninstall old versions. This will make misconfiguration errors explicit.

### 3. Check your configuration:

- Check where your JAVA_HOME environment variable points to.
- Check which java version you use to run the program. In IntelliJ check:

  - File -> Project Structure... -> Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK:
  - File -> Project Structure... -> Platform Settings -> SDKs

### 4. Copy whole keystore from the new Java version

If you develop under the JDK other than the latest available - try to replace the `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts` file with the new one from the latest installed JRE (make a backup copy first) as @jeremy-goodell suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21507568/355438)

### 5. Add certificate(s) to your keystore

If nothing above solves your problem use `keytool` to save certificate(s) to the Java's keystore:

```
keytool -trustcacerts -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -importcert -alias <alias_name> -file <path_to_crt_file>
```

File with the certificate can be obtained from the browser as @MagGGG suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/355438).

Note 1: you may need to repeat this for every certificate in the chain to you site's certificate. Start from the root one.

Note 2: `<alias_name>` should be unique among the keys in the store or `keytool` will show an error.

To get list of all the certificates in the store you may run:

```
keytool -list -trustcacerts -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

In case something goes wrong this will help you to remove certificate from the store:

```
keytool -delete -alias <alias_name> -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

Comment: With how well-elaborated this is, it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Should be `keytool -list -trustcacerts -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass changeit` on Mac

Comment: I was trying to access a site with a LetsEncrypt-generated certificate, and upgrading to a Java version >= 8u101 fixed the issue - https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/

Answer (score 56):

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

It is used for jump the certificate validation.

### **Warning!**

Only use for development purposes for this is unsecure!

Comment: @gorums How to setup it in Eclipse?

Comment: Do NOT do this unless you want to risk running arbitrary malicious code on your machine.

Downvoted as it risks compromising any machine that runs it.

Comment: Just because it 'works' doesn't mean it's safe, you're putting everyone that follows this advice at risk. Have my downvote

Comment: @AceKing The point is that it's *not* trusted code if you don't validate the certificate. That said, I think this is still a useful answer. People doing it just need to understand the risks.

Comment: Totally agree with you @MichaelMior

Comment: I you trust the server that hold the repositories this the way to go.

Comment: @MichaelMior If you know to trust the URL, you know to trust the code. You should only skip certificate validation if you only use URLs you know well (such as your company's Jira repository), but that should be common sense. Of course there can still be issues if a corrupted hosts file or something similar remaps the URL to a malicious server, but if that's happening you're already screwed anyway.

Comment: @EgorHans That's rather dangerous and if you take that approach, you leave yourself open to MITM attacks. One of the main points of certificate validation is that you're *not *screwed if someone hijacks a URL because you know when this happens.

Comment: @EgorHans Yeah, you can only trust a URL if you verify the authenticity of it, which is done with SSL. You can't just trust a URL with SSL disabled, since as Michael said, anyone can man-in-the-middle and pretend to own that address when SSL is disabled.

Comment: This is a really reckless solution. Cyber attacks are everywhere; all it takes is one unsecured machine within an organisation to get through to its systems.

Comment: In my opinion, this solution is only acceptable for one particular scenario: You are absolutely sure what you're doing and you're only dealing with your own certificate for your own URL. For example, you run integration tests against your local development instance - here it could make sense to skip cert validation. Still, with great power...

Answer (score 35):

### Mac

The accepted answer does not work for Mac as there is no <kbd>Export</kbd> button available in Mac (Chrome or Firefox). Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59466184/10819573) to download the certificate and follow the next steps as mentioned below:

1. **List all certificates installed in the keystore**:

```
cd $JAVA_HOME/lib/security
keytool -list -keystore cacerts
```

**Notes:**

- The default password of the keystore is: `changeit`.
- For Java-8 or lower version use the command, `cd $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security`

2. **Before you import the certificate in the keystore, make a backup of the keystore**:

```
sudo cp cacerts cacerts.bak
```

3. **Import the downloaded certificate in the keystore**:

```
sudo keytool -importcert -alias youralias -file /path/to/the/downloaded/certificate -keystore cacerts
```

4. **Check if the certificate is stored in the keystore**:

```
sudo keytool -list -keystore cacerts -alias youralias
```

If you want to see more detailed information, add the `-v` flag:

```
sudo keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts -alias youralias
```

Comment: If I need a certificate to access the local host from mac, how to generate the certificate?

Comment: This answer worked for me. Regarding Certificate, I was facing this problem when we are running behind a company proxy. In my case it's zscaler.
Open Key chain access, export CA certificate.(Select CA certificate, File->export items and save with the desired name)

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. This is helpful

Comment: On the newer version of Chrome, you had the export option when showing the certificate (bottom right corner).

Answer (score 32):

I have stumbled upon this issue which took many hours of research to fix, specially with auto-generated certificates, which unlike Official ones, are quite tricky and Java does not like them that much.

Please check the following link: [Solve Problem with certificates in Java](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target)

Basically you have to add the certificate from the server to the Java Home certs.

1. Generate or Get your certificate and configure Tomcat to use it in Servers.xml
2. Download the Java source code of the class `InstallCert` and execute it while the server is running, providing the following arguments `server[:port]`. No password is needed, as the original password works for the Java certs ("changeit").
3. The Program will connect to the server and Java will throw an exception, it will analyze the certificate provided by the server and allow you to create a `jssecerts` file inside the directory where you executed the Program (If executed from Eclipse then make sure you configure the Work directory in `Run -> Configurations`).
4. Manually copy that file to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security`

After following these steps, the connections with the certificate will not generate exceptions anymore within Java.

The following source code is important and it disappeared from (Sun) Oracle blogs, the only page I found it was on the link provided, therefore I am attaching it in the answer for any reference.

```
/*
 * Copyright 2006 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Sun Microsystems nor the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
/**
 * Originally from:
 * http://blogs.sun.com/andreas/resource/InstallCert.java
 * Use:
 * java InstallCert hostname
 * Example:
 *% java InstallCert ecc.fedora.redhat.com
 */

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/**
 * Class used to add the server's certificate to the KeyStore
 * with your trusted certificates.
 */
public class InstallCert {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String host;
        int port;
        char[] passphrase;
        if ((args.length == 1) || (args.length == 2)) {
            String[] c = args[0].split(":");
            host = c[0];
            port = (c.length == 1) ? 443 : Integer.parseInt(c[1]);
            String p = (args.length == 1) ? "changeit" : args[1];
            passphrase = p.toCharArray();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: java InstallCert [:port] [passphrase]");
            return;
        }

        File file = new File("jssecacerts");
        if (file.isFile() == false) {
            char SEP = File.separatorChar;
            File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP
                    + "lib" + SEP + "security");
            file = new File(dir, "jssecacerts");
            if (file.isFile() == false) {
                file = new File(dir, "cacerts");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Loading KeyStore " + file + "...");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(in, passphrase);
        in.close();

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManagerFactory tmf =
                TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);
        X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
        SavingTrustManager tm = new SavingTrustManager(defaultTrustManager);
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
        SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();

        System.out.println("Opening connection to " + host + ":" + port + "...");
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
        socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting SSL handshake...");
            socket.startHandshake();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("No errors, certificate is already trusted");
        } catch (SSLException e) {
            System.out.println();
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        X509Certificate[] chain = tm.chain;
        if (chain == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not obtain server certificate chain");
            return;
        }

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Server sent " + chain.length + " certificate(s):");
        System.out.println();
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
            X509Certificate cert = chain[i];
            System.out.println
                    (" " + (i + 1) + " Subject " + cert.getSubjectDN());
            System.out.println("   Issuer  " + cert.getIssuerDN());
            sha1.update(cert.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("   sha1    " + toHexString(sha1.digest()));
            md5.update(cert.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("   md5     " + toHexString(md5.digest()));
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter certificate to add to trusted keystore or 'q' to quit: [1]");
        String line = reader.readLine().trim();
        int k;
        try {
            k = (line.length() == 0) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(line) - 1;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("KeyStore not changed");
            return;
        }

        X509Certificate cert = chain[k];
        String alias = host + "-" + (k + 1);
        ks.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jssecacerts");
        ks.store(out, passphrase);
        out.close();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(cert);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println
                ("Added certificate to keystore 'jssecacerts' using alias '"
                        + alias + "'");
    }

    private static final char[] HEXDIGITS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    private static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 3);
        for (int b : bytes) {
            b &= 0xff;
            sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b >> 4]);
            sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b & 15]);
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static class SavingTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        private final X509TrustManager tm;
        private X509Certificate[] chain;

        SavingTrustManager(X509TrustManager tm) {
            this.tm = tm;
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            this.chain = chain;
            tm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the file created is jssecacerts!

Comment: I tried using this solution for Java 7 and 8. While running on Java 7, I got protocol_version or handshake_failure for all the remote repository urls I tried with. `SandeepanNath:test sandeepan.nath$ java InstallCert repo1.maven.org:443
Loading KeyStore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts...
Opening connection to repo1.maven.org:443 ...
Starting SSL handshake...

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version .. Could not obtain server certificate chain`

Answer (score 25):

I wanted to import certificate for `smtp.gmail.com`. The only solution that worked for me is

1. Enter command to view this certificate

   ```
   D:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
   ```
2. Copy and save the lines between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` into a file, `gmail.cer`
3. Run

   ```
   keytool -import -alias smtp.gmail.com -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -file C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\gmail.cer
   ```
4. Enter password: `changeit`
5. Click "Yes" to import the certificate
6. Restart Java

Now run the command and you are good to go.

Comment: If you are getting "Input not an X.509 certificate" error message during certificate import, make sure you copied BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE text also.

Comment: Password is changeit with an n (or changeme on mac)

Answer (score 23):

This isn't a Twitter-specific answer, but this is the question that comes up when you search for this error. If your system is receiving this error when connecting to a website that **appears to have a valid certificate when viewed in a web browser**, that probably means **that website has an incomplete certificate chain**.

For a brief summary of the problem: Certificate Authorities don't use their Root Certificate to sign just any old certificate. Instead, they (usually) sign *intermediate* certificates that also have the Certificate Authority flag set (that is, are allowed to sign certificates). Then when you purchase a certificate from a CA, they sign your CSR with one of these intermediate certificates.

Your Java trust store most likely only has the Root Cert, not the intermediate ones.

A misconfigured site might return *just* their signed cert. Problem: it was signed with an intermediate cert that's not in your trust store. Browsers will handle this problem by downloading or using a cached intermediate certificate; this maximizes website compatibility. Java and tools like OpenSSL, however, won't. And that will cause the error in the question.

You can verify this suspicion by using the [Qualys SSL Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html). If you run that against a site and it says

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete.

then that confirms it. You can also see this by looking at the certification paths and seeing the text *Extra Download*.

How to fix it: the server administrator needs to configure the web server to return the intermediate certificates as well. For Comodo, for example, this is where the `.ca-bundle` file comes in handy. For example, in an Apache configuration with mod_ssl, you'd use the `SSLCertificateChainFile` configuration setting. For nginx, you need to concatenate the intermediate certificates and the signed certificate and use that in the SSL cert configuration. You can find more by searching for "incomplete certificate chain" online.

Comment: You are brilliant.  Thank you!  I had an issue with the new buildout of my Java server because I forgot to remove the # in front of SSLCertificateChainFile!!!  Really well explained.

Answer (score 17):

I had a slightly different situation, when both JDK and JRE 1.8.0_112 were present on my system.

I imported the new CA certificates into `[JDK_FOLDER]\jre\lib\security\cacerts` using the already known command:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -alias <new_ca_alias> -file <path_to_ca_cert_file>
```

Still, I kept getting the same *PKIX path building failed* error.

I added debug information to the java CLI, by using `java -Djavax.net.debug=all ... > debug.log`. In the debug.log file, the line that begins with *trustStore is:* actually pointed to the cacerts store found in `[JRE_FOLDER]\lib\security\cacerts`.

In my case the solution was to copy the cacerts file used by JDK (which had the new CAs added) over the one used by the JRE and that fixed the issue.

Comment: I directly imported certs I needed into the JRE/lib/security/cacerts using keytool, but it changed nothing for me :( still getting the same error, I also added them via the IDE, or even into the classpath and added a Bean to specify the keystore location !! It's crazy AF !

Answer (score 15):

After struggling for half-day, found one more way to solve this problem. I was able to solve this in MAC 10.15.5 ( Catalina). Followed the below steps.

- This problem occurs when we are running behind a company proxy , In my case its Zscaler.
- Open Key chain access, export CA certificate.(Select CA certificate, `File->export items` and save with the desired name)
- Copy the path of existing cacerts from java folder(`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts`
  )
- Open terminal and navigate to the Keytool folder (`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin`
  )
- Run the below command.
- `Keytool -importcert - file (Path to exported cert from the keychainaccess) -alias (give a name) -keystore (Path of existing cacerts from java folder)`
- `sudo Keytool -importcert -file /Users/Desktop/RootCA.cer -alias demo -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts`
- It will ask for password , give it as : `changeit`
- It asks for confirmation , Say : yes

After all of these steps, Quit eclipse and terminal start fresh session.

Comment: How did you get CA certificate in key chain access? My key chain access doesn't have any certificates.

Answer (score 13):

**Issue Background:**

I was getting following error when i try to run mvn clean install in my project and through Netbeans IDE clean and build option.
This issue is due to certificate not available when we download through NET beans IDE/through command prompt, but able to download the files through the browser.

**Error**:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.java.project:product:jar:1.0.32 from/to repo-local (https://url/local-repo): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

**Resolution:**

**1. Download the certificate of the Url in question:**

- Launch IE by "run as adminstrator" (otherwise, we will not be able to download the certificate)
- Enter the url in IE-> https://url/local-repo
  (In my case this url had a untrusted certificate[image].)
- Download the certificate by clicking on Certificate error -> view certificate
- Select Details tab -> copy to file -> next -> select "DER encoded binary X.509 (.CER)
- save the certificate in some location, example : c:/user/sheldon/desktop/product.cer
- Congrats! you have successfully downloaded the certificate for the site

**2. Now install the key store to fix the issue.**

- Run the keytool command to append the downloaded keystore into the
     existing certificate file.
- **Command:  Below command in the bin folder of jdk (JAVA_HOME)**.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\bin>keytool -importcert -file
>   "C:/user/sheldon/desktop/product.cer" -alias product -keystore
>   "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_141/jre/lib/security/cacerts".

- You will be prompted to enter password.  Enter keystore password:
  enter "changeit" again for "Trust this certificate? [no]:", enter 
  "yes"

Sample command line commands/output:

```
keytool -importcert -file "C:/Users/sheldon/Desktop/product.cer" -alias product -keystore "C:/Program iles/Java/jdk1.8.0_141/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
Enter keystore password:
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
```

- Contgrats! now you should have got rid of "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException" error in your Netbeans IDE.

Comment: Hi I followed all the steps but no luck :(

Comment: do you have any other certificate in the path other than cacerts? if you have some other, try to add it to that certificate

Comment: Thanks @Barani r , It was my mistake I was executing command from jre and using JDK in my eclipse

Comment: Wasn't able to download certificate but after, "run as administrator", worked well.

Comment: @Baranir I went to the trouble of loggin in (didn't remember if my main account was linked through Facebook, Google or SO) just to upvote this answer. At first it wasn't working but turns out I was missing the -keystore parameter. People, please don't omit the -keystore parameter. It won't work and you will pull out some of the few remaining hair on your head. Jokes aside,  +1 for a solid answer.

Answer (score 13):

**This is a solution but in form of my story with this problem:**

I was almost dead trying all the solutions given above(for 3 days ) and nothing worked for me.

I lost all hope.

I contacted my security team regarding this because I was behind a proxy and they told me that they had recently updated their security policy.

Later they issued a new "cacerts" file which contains all the certificates.

I removed the `cacerts` file which is present inside `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security` and it solved my problem.

So if you are facing this issue it might be from your network team also like this.

Answer (score 12):

The reason, we get above error is that JDK is bundled with a lot of trusted Certificate Authority(CA) certificates into a file called ‘cacerts’ but this file has no clue of our self-signed certificate. In other words, the cacerts file doesn’t have our self-signed certificate imported and thus doesn’t treat it as a trusted entity and hence it gives the above error.

[How to fix the above error](http://www.littlebigextra.com/how-to-fix-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception/)

To fix the above error, all we need is to import the self-signed certificate into the cacerts file.

First, locate the cacerts file. We will need to find out the JDK location. If you are running your application through one of the IDE’s like Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea go to project settings and figure out what is the JDK location.
For e.g on a Mac OS typical location of cacerts file would be at this location /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ {{JDK_version}}/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security
on a Window’s machine it would be under {{Installation_directory}}/{{JDK_version}}/jre/lib/security

Once you have located the cacerts file, now we need to import our self-signed certificate to this cacerts file. Check the last article, if you don’t know how to generate the self-signed certificate correctly.

If you don’t have a certificate file(.crt) and just have a .jks file you can generate a .crt file by using below command. In case you already have a .crt/.pem file then you can ignore below command

##To generate certificate from keystore(.jks file) ####

```
keytool -export -keystore keystore.jks -alias selfsigned -file selfsigned.crt
```

Above step will generate a file called selfsigned.crt.Now Import the certificate to cacerts

Now add the certificate to JRE/lib/security/cacerts (trustore)

```
keytool -importcert -file selfsigned.crt -alias selfsigned -keystore {{cacerts path}}
```

for e.g

```
keytool -importcert -file selfsigned.nextgen.crt -alias selfsigned.nextgen -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

That’s all, restart your application and it should work fine. If it still doesn’t work and get an SSL handshake exception. It probably means you are using different domain then registered in the certificate.

The Link [with detailed explanation and  step by step resolution is over here.](http://www.littlebigextra.com/how-to-fix-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception/)

Comment: Could you elaborate more on resolving this?

"If it still doesn’t work and get an SSL handshake exception. It probably means you are using different domain than registered in the certificate."

Answer (score 11):

Simple Steps to resolve this Exception, (I did it on java 11),

- First you need to Download the public SSL certificate file of the target domain that you are trying to call,for that
- Open the target domain website in the chrome (Example: https://amazonservice.domain.com)
- Click on the small lock icon before the URL in the browser
- Click View certificates
- Now Click on Certificate is valid as shown below
- [image]
- Now a new Popup will open as shown below,
  [image: Go]
- Open the details tab
- Select the RootCert at the top
- Click Export and save the .cer file to your system in a directory

Now you have the public keystore of your target domain which you are trying to call in your java application,now we need to impot that keystore into you jre,for that go to the $JAVA_HOME/bin directory and run the following command

```
./keytool -importcert -alias someAliasName -keystore {JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts -file {PathToDownloads}/certificateFileName.cer
```

It will ask you for password, enter the password if you know, the default password for the certificate is `changeit`

References

1. https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-import-a-public-ssl-certificate-into-a-jvm-867025849.html
2. https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-error-779355358.html

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, it is not the `RootCert` that worked for me as we have a zscaler firewalll running in office. In my case the specific certificate of the site, for example, `repo.maven.apache.org` usually comes at the bottom end of the certificate hierarchy (Although your picture shows the right selection, you mentioned to select the RootCert at the top)

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same issue and get it resolved using the below simple steps:

1) Download the InstallCert.java from google

2) Compile it using **javac InstallCert.java**

3) Run InstallCert.java using **java InstallCert.java**, with the hostname and https port, and press “1” when asking for input. It will add the “localhost” as a trusted keystore, and generate a file named “jssecacerts“ as below:

**java InstallCert localhost:443**

4) copy the jssecacerts into $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security folder

Main source to resolve the issue here is:

https://ankurjain26.blogspot.in/2017/11/javaxnetsslsslhandshakeexception.html

Comment: Link is broken.However it does work for me.

Comment: https://github.com/escline/InstallCert can get the InstallCert.java file from here. After hours of struggle, this solved the issue for me. And this seems like the best way to address this issue. Wondering why this is not the top-voted.

Answer (score 8):

Problem is, your eclipse is not able to connect the site which actually it is trying to.
I have faced similar issue and below given solution worked for me.

1. Turn off any third party internet security application e.g. Zscaler
2. Sometimes also need to disconnect VPN if you are connected.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Adding `cacerts` did not work for me.
After enabling log with flag `-Djavax.net.debug=all`, then came to know java reading from `jssecacerts`.

Import to `jssecacerts` worked finally.

Comment: The missing explanation here is that Java will use `jssecacerts` if present, otherwise `cacerts`.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is mostly due to the request is being blocked by the application in our system that protect us from the cyberattacks.

In my case, I tried accessing a trusted API service so I just resolved it by adding the zscaler certicate to the `lib/security/cacerts` file of my jdk 17, which is being used in the IDE by executing the below keytool command in the cmd.

```
keytool -keystore  "C:\dev\java\jdk-17.0.7\lib\security\cacerts" -import -alias zscalarCert -file "C:\Users\theri\Documents\zscalar-cert.crt"

password:- changeit
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, certificate error popped up because I had fiddler running in background and that messes up with certificate. It acts as a proxy so close that and restart eclipse.

Comment: same prob happening in eclipse , even after closing all application

Comment: @Atihska this really resolved my issue. Thank you and really appreciated

Comment: Same, I had forgotten that Charles Proxy was running, and got that error. After stopping Charles, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question while trying to install the Cucumber-Eclipse plugin in Eclipse via their update site.  I received the same SunCertPathBuilderException error:

```
Unable to read repository at http://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/content.xml.
    Unable to read repository at http://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/content.xml.
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

While some of the other answers are appropriate and helpful for this question's given situation, they were nevertheless unhelpful and misleading for my issue.

In my case, the issue was that the URL provided for their update site is:

> https://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site

However when navigating to it via a browser, it redirected to (note the added "**.github**"):

> http://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/

So the resolution is to simply use the redirected version of the update site URL when adding the update site in eclipse.

Comment: Are you sure you are answering the right question? There is no mentioning of cucumber in the original question ...

Comment: I feel that I am.  I received the same SunCertPathBuilderException error and while searching for a resolution, found this question as well as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore).  However, neither of them had appropriate solution for my situation.

I wasn't trying to answer the specific question of how to add the Cucumber-Eclipse plugin site to eclipse.  I wanted to provide context for the issue I faced (URL redirection) and explain how it was resolved.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it clear that I received the same error, noting that the underlying issue and solution were different.  I feel this is valid since others may find this question when searching on the same error.  Please consider changing your vote if you feel this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. Makes things much clearer, reversed my downvote

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks for taking the time to review it again.

Answer (score 4):

If you are still getting this error

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target
```

after executing the below command and restarting the java process or restart the system

```
keytool -import -alias certificatealias -keystore C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\security\cacerts -file certificate.cer
```

**If there is some issue in JDK, Try to install JDK from a trusted provider.
Once you reinstalled it from trusted provider you won't face this issue.**

Comment: certainly you need to rename your crt into cer

Answer (score 4):

If you're facing issues with below exception:

**Issue:** javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed ..... unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

**Cause:** SSL Handshake is failing because the require server certificate is not present at client. For JAVA application stack it uses its own certificate store either in JRE or JDK locations:

1. **JRE:** jre/lib/security/cacerts
2. **JDK:** :\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\lib/security/cacerts

**Solution:** you need to register the certificate inside cacerts folder of JAVA set up using below command:

**keytool -import -alias {certificate-name} -keystore  "{absolute-path-of-cacerts-directory}" -file {.cer-file-location}**

This utility uses default password as "changeit". Please enter this password when get prompted.

If keytool is not recognized please note that this .exe is part of JRE or JDK bin folder hence adding that path inside local machine environment variable called "Path" should fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

goals:

1. use https connections
2. verify SSL chains
3. do not deal with cacerts
4. add certificate in runtime
5. do not lose certificates from cacerts

How to do it:

1. define own keystore
2. put certificate into keystore
3. redefine SSL default context with our custom class
4. ???
5. profit

My Keystore wrapper file:

```
public class CertificateManager {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CertificateManager.class);

    private String keyStoreLocation;
    private String keyStorePassword;
    private X509TrustManager myTrustManager;
    private static KeyStore myTrustStore;

    public CertificateManager(String keyStoreLocation, String keyStorePassword) throws Exception {
        this.keyStoreLocation = keyStoreLocation;
        this.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
        myTrustStore = createKeyStore(keyStoreLocation, keyStorePassword);
    }

    public void addCustomCertificate(String certFileName, String certificateAlias)
            throws Exception {
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init((KeyStore) null);
        Certificate certificate = myTrustStore.getCertificate(certificateAlias);
        if (certificate == null) {
            logger.info("Certificate not exists");
            addCertificate(certFileName, certificateAlias);
        } else {
            logger.info("Certificate exists");
        }
        tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(myTrustStore);
        for (TrustManager tm : tmf.getTrustManagers()) {
            if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                setMytrustManager((X509TrustManager) tm);
                logger.info("Trust manager found");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private InputStream fullStream(String fname) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream resource = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fname);
        try {
            if (resource != null) {
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(resource);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[dis.available()];
                dis.readFully(bytes);
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            } else {
                logger.info("resource not found");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("exception in certificate fetching as resource", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static KeyStore createKeyStore(String keystore, String pass) throws Exception {
        try {
            InputStream in = CertificateManager.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(keystore);
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(in, pass.toCharArray());
            logger.info("Keystore was created from resource file");
            return keyStore;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Fail to create keystore from resource file");
        }

        File file = new File(keystore);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        if (file.exists()) {
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), pass.toCharArray());
            logger.info("Default keystore loaded");
        } else {
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(file), pass.toCharArray());
            logger.info("New keystore created");
        }
        return keyStore;
    }

    private void addCertificate(String certFileName, String certificateAlias) throws CertificateException,
            IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream certStream = fullStream(certFileName);
        Certificate certs = cf.generateCertificate(certStream);
        myTrustStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, certs);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getKeyStoreLocation());
        myTrustStore.store(out, getKeyStorePassword().toCharArray());
        out.close();
        logger.info("Certificate pushed");
    }

    public String getKeyStoreLocation() {
        return keyStoreLocation;
    }

    public String getKeyStorePassword() {
        return keyStorePassword;
    }
    public X509TrustManager getMytrustManager() {
        return myTrustManager;
    }
    public void setMytrustManager(X509TrustManager myTrustManager) {
        this.myTrustManager = myTrustManager;
    }
}
```

This class will create keystore if necessary, and will be able to manage certificates inside of it. Now class for SSL context:

```
public class CustomTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CertificateManager.class);

    private static SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;
    private static CustomTrustManager instance = new CustomTrustManager();
    private static List<CertificateManager> register = new ArrayList<>();

    public static CustomTrustManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private X509TrustManager defaultTm;

    public void register(CertificateManager certificateManager) {
        for(CertificateManager manager : register) {
            if(manager == certificateManager) {
                logger.info("Certificate manager already registered");
                return;
            }
        }
        register.add(certificateManager);
        logger.info("New Certificate manager registered");
    }

    private CustomTrustManager() {
        try {
            String algorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);

            tmf.init((KeyStore) null);
            boolean found = false;
            for (TrustManager tm : tmf.getTrustManagers()) {
                if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                    defaultTm = (X509TrustManager) tm;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found) {
                logger.info("Default trust manager found");
            } else {
                logger.warn("Default trust manager was not found");
            }

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{this}, null);
            SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
            socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);


            logger.info("Custom trust manager was set");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException e) {
            logger.warn("Custom trust manager can't be set");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        List<X509Certificate> out = new ArrayList<>();
        if (defaultTm != null) {
            out.addAll(Arrays.asList(defaultTm.getAcceptedIssuers()));
        }
        int defaultCount = out.size();
        logger.info("Default trust manager contain " + defaultCount + " certficates");
        for(CertificateManager manager : register) {
            X509TrustManager customTrustManager = manager.getMytrustManager();
            X509Certificate[] issuers = customTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
            out.addAll(Arrays.asList(issuers));
        }
        logger.info("Custom trust managers contain " + (out.size() - defaultCount) + " certficates");
        X509Certificate[] arrayOut = new X509Certificate[out.size()];
        return out.toArray(arrayOut);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                   String authType) throws CertificateException {
        for(CertificateManager certificateManager : register) {
            X509TrustManager customTrustManager = certificateManager.getMytrustManager();
            try {
                customTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
                logger.info("Certificate chain (server) was aproved by custom trust manager");
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        if (defaultTm != null) {
            defaultTm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
            logger.info("Certificate chain (server) was aproved by default trust manager");
        } else {
            logger.info("Certificate chain (server) was rejected");
            throw new CertificateException("Can't check server trusted certificate.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                   String authType) throws CertificateException {
        try {
            if (defaultTm != null) {
                defaultTm.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
                logger.info("Certificate chain (client) was aproved by default trust manager");
            } else {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            for(CertificateManager certificateManager : register) {
                X509TrustManager customTrustManager = certificateManager.getMytrustManager();
                try {
                    customTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
                    logger.info("Certificate chain (client) was aproved by custom trust manager");
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
            }
            logger.info("Certificate chain (client) was rejected");
            throw new CertificateException("Can't check client trusted certificate.");
        }
    }

    public SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {
        return socketFactory;
    }
}
```

This class made as singleton, because only one defaultSSL context allowed. So, now usage:

```
            CertificateManager certificateManager = new CertificateManager("C:\\myapplication\\mykeystore.jks", "changeit");
            String certificatePath = "C:\\myapplication\\public_key_for_your_ssl_service.crt";
            try {
                certificateManager.addCustomCertificate(certificatePath, "alias_for_public_key_for_your_ssl_service");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Can't add custom certificate");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            CustomTrustManager.getInstance().register(certificateManager);
```

Possibly, it will not work with this settings, because I keep certificate file inside of resource folder, so my path is not absolute. But generally, it work perfectly.

Comment: This double misuse of `available()` is specifically warned against in its own Javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

If your repository URL also work on HTTP and the security is not a concern, you can go to **settings.xml** (often, but not always, located in `%USERPROFILE%/.m2`) and **replace HTTPS with HTTP** for `<repository>` and `<pluginRepository>` URLs.

For example, this:

```
<repository>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>libs-release</name>
    <url>https://<artifactory>/libs-release</url>
</repository>
```

should be replaced by this:

```
<repository>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>libs-release</name>
    <url>https://<artifactory>/libs-release</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: what's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

I was using my own trust store rather than JRE one by passing arg `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=`

I was getting this error regardless of certs in truststore. The issue for me was the ordering of of the properties passed on arg line. 
When i put `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=`& `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=` **before** `-Dspring.config.location=` & `-jar` args i was able to successfully invoke my rest call over https.

Comment: This worked for me when I was trying to figure out how to get maven to behave properly. `-"Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore"=<path>` is all I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue on Windows Server 2016 with Java 8, by importing cert from `pkcs12` store to `cacerts` keystore.

Path to pkcs12 store: 

`C:\Apps\pkcs12.pfx`

Path to Java cacerts:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\security\cacerts`

Path to keytool:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin`

After possitioning to folder with keytool in command prompt (as administrator), command to import cert from `pkcs12` to `cacerts` is as follows:

`keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Apps\pkcs12.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\security\cacerts" -deststoretype JKS`

You will be prompted to:
 1. enter destination keystore password (cacerts pasword, default is "changeit")
 2. enter source keystore password (pkcs12 password)

For changes to take effect, restart server machine (or just restart JVM).

Comment: I used this approach on a Mac and it just worked. My Cert was of course self signed and generated to I imported the .pfx file which I had generated on my windows adfs server.
Using Java 10 for my app
Thanks

Comment: Path to Java cacerts should be:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\jre\lib\security\cacerts` instead of `Java\jre1.8...` `Java\jdk1.8...\jre\` should be used

Answer (score 3):

I ran into same issue but updating wrong jre on my linux machine. It is highly likely that tomcat is using different jre and your cli prompt is configured to use a different jre.

Make sure you are picking up the correct jre.

Step #1:

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat
```

You will see some thing like:

```
root     29855     1  3 17:54 pts/3    00:00:42 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin/java
```

Now use this:

```
keytool -import -alias example -keystore  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file cert.cer
PWD: changeit
```

*.cer file can be geneated as shown below: (or you can use your own)

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -outform pem -outform der -out cert.cer
```

Answer (score 2):

In case your **host sits behind firewall/proxy** , use following command in cmd:

```
keytool -J-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy_hostname> -J-Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy_port> -printcert -rfc -sslserver <remote_host_name:remote_ssl_port>
```

Replace `<proxy_hostname>` and `<proxy_port>` with the HTTP proxy server that is configured. Replace `<remote_host_name:remote_ssl_port>` with one of the remote host (basically url) and port having the certification problem.

Take the last certificate content printed and copy it (also copy begin and end certificate). Paste it in text file and give *.crt*  extension to it . Now import this certificate to *cacerts* using java keytool command and it should work .

```
keytool -importcert -file <filename>.crt -alias randomaliasname -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Comment: This post really saved my day. I was not able to solve the issue until I tweaked with above settings by adding proxy details. Worked like a champ.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solutions did not work for me. I ended up using this workaround. Keep in mind, not ideal.

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dmaven.resolver.transport=wagon
```

Answer (score 1):

1-First of all, import you'r crt file into {JAVA_HOME}/jre/security/cacerts, if you still faced with this exception, change you'r jdk version. For example from `jdk1.8.0_17` to `jdk1.8.0_231`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue with Java 8 but it got solved after upgrading to Java 11

Answer (score 1):

Above suggestions work however I wanted a more simple and command line only solution as I need it relatively often so I came up with `jssl`.

**TLDR:**
`jssl example.com install`
`jssl example.com ping`
`jssl example.com uninstall`

You can install jssl via homebrew:
`brew install pmamico/java/jssl`
or without homebrew:
`curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmamico/java-ssl-tools/main/install.sh | bash`

It works on Windows, macOS and Linux also.
See more at https://github.com/pmamico/java-ssl-tools

Comment: WOW, Awesome. This is indispensible tool

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this error in Flutter project.

The issue was due to the restriction put by the security softwares installed in my company's laptop.

The solution was given by the IT team that connect to the VPN provided by company. Then I was able to download the required files and the project ran successfully.

Note: I needed to connect only one time to the company's VPN. Once the project ran successfully, then I didn't need to connect to VPN.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers above regarding getting the certificate from the browser and importing it into your JRE `cacerts` are correct. I just wanted to clarify why this is happening and why is this necessary sometimes?

Simply put, this could happen in 2 cases:

1. When the certificate used by the target server is signed by an unknown CA (Certificate Authority). By unknown here is meant - unknown to your java. Java maintains a list of trusted CAs in its cacert and if the certificate was signed by some unknown CA or an incomplete set of CAs, the error will happen
2. When you are behind a proxy which sniffs the https connection and replaces the target server certificate with its own certificate (e.g. Zscaler). Same thing, you need to get that certificate and import it into your JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Here normally this kind of exception occurs when there is mismatch in the PATH of trusted certificate. Check the configuration or path where this server certificate is required for secured communication.

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact configuration where i can install certificate. 
Actaully i am having issue regarding this, i had installed the certificate regarding this issue using **keytool**, this works for around 20-30 mins and then the server issue same error again.

Please help me. I have been stucked in this issue for 2 days.

Comment: I think the certificate changes every 20-30 minutes

Comment: I facing similar problem but for issue is :
MY java pick default location for$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts of Java applications though i have supplied -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/myapp/app.jks

Can any one help me on this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821785/why-java-pick-default-location-for-keystore-truststore-of-java-applications-when?noredirect=1#comment55409847_33821785

Answer (score 0):

**Working steps via Linux terminal ( steps below )**

1. download the certs for the URL complaining ( for me `repo.maven.apache.org` was complaining )

```html
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect repo.maven.apache.org:443 </dev/null | sed -n -e '/-.BEGIN/,/-.END/ p' > /tmp/maven_repo.pem
```

2. Extract the certificate information to existing keystore file ( let's say `abc.jks` )

```html
sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -trustcacerts -keystore /home/akhilesh/abc.jks  -storepass changeit -importcert -alias mavenrepo -file /tmp/maven_repo.pem
```

3. If you do not have existing keystore file then you can add it to `${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts`

```html
sudo ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/keytool -importcert -alias "MavenCert" -keystore /${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts -file /tmp/maven_repo.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case a proxy software installed on my mac was the culprit.

I faced this when I was trying build project on my Macbook. I tried so many solutions but none worked. Finally saw that the IT team had installed a proxy software and suspected that the proxy software could be blocking gradle to download the dependencies. I connected with IT Team and got the proxy uninstalled and then synced the project and it worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

Although alot answers have been provided, I would like to suggest a simple alternative based on [certificate ripper](https://github.com/Hakky54/certificate-ripper) which I have built myself. It extracts the server certificate and adds it the cacert truststore of the jdk. See below for the command.

```
crip export jks -u=https://[HOST:[PORT] -d=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

In some cases you need to run it with sudo or admin rights. It is available for Windows, Mac and Linx. Binaries can be found here: [certificate ripper binaries](https://github.com/Hakky54/certificate-ripper/releases)

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is not about fixing certificate validation from the source but the google landed me here because an error message I faced was the same.

Given:

1. Windows 10
2. company's proxy behind (don't know exactly what's going on behind corporate's network but have Symantic Endpoint Protection is being run locally)
3. several JDKs installed locally (8-21). JAVA_HOME points out the coretto-17.
4. a simple brand new spring boot project generated from the spring-initializer.io (old gradle projects behave the same).
5. 

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.3'

}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.32'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.32'
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'gradle-fail'
```

The output I was trying to fix:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradle'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:3.2.3.
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.2.3 > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.3
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:3.2.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-buildpack-platform/3.2.3/spring-boot-buildpack-platform-3.2.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-buildpack-platform/3.2.3/spring-boot-buildpack-platform-3.2.3.pom'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I tried to build project via idea, gradle 8.5(7.5, 8.7) and gradle wrapper 8.5. I have to admit that the same project built via maven was compiled successfully.

The most voted solution didn't help. The gradle plugin portal is being redirected to jcenter repo even though it has been deprecated. Local build is still attempting to download libs from the jcenter.

My workaround was to disable jcenter repo and enforce using maven central or another maven repo for plugin resolution. Eventually I managed to fix it.
The final solution is pretty simple. Just needed to add mavenCentral to plugin management repository config:

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = 'gradle-failed'
```

Answer (score -1):

It's addition to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/1491414. Thanks @MagGGG

- Please make sure you have administrator permission
- Please use double quotes for the keystore path (-keystore  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\security\cacerts") because in Windows OS the default installs location will be Program Files and you will get an error because of space between Program Files.

Answer (score -1):

**I fixed this using below method-**

1. Copy url which is having connecting issue
2. Go to Android Studio->Settings->Http settings
3. In 'Test Connection', paste that url and press ok
4. On Ok click, Android Studio will ask to import certificate of that
   url, import it
5. That's it. Nothing else to be done and my issue was gone. No need to
   restart studio as well.

Answer (score -1):

When you have above error with atlassian software ex. jira

```
2018-08-18 11:35:00,312 Caesium-1-4 WARN anonymous    Default Mail Handler [c.a.mail.incoming.mailfetcherservice] Default Mail Handler[10001]: javax.mail.MessagingException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target while connecting to host 'imap.xyz.pl' as user 'jira@xyz.pl' via protocol 'imaps, caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

you can add certs to it's trusted keystore (change missing_ca to proper cert name):

```
keytool -importcert -file missing_ca.crt -alias missing_ca -keystore /opt/atlassian/jira/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

If asked for password put `changeit` and confirm `y`

After that simply restart jira.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using CloudFoundry and run into certificate issue then you'd have to make sure that you push the jar again with the keystore-service with the certificate in it. Simply unbind, bind and restart won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try copying java cacerts:

`cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-9.b11.fc28.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Answer (score -1):

If you are seeing this issue in a linux container when java application is trying to communicate with another application/site, it is because the certificate have been imported incorrectly into the load balancer. There is sequence of steps to be followed for importing certificates and that if not done correctly, you will see issues like

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target
```

Once the certs are imported correctly, it should be done. No need to tinker with any JDK certs.

Answer (score -1):

download the cert file, and update the keystore with the certificate file as in the below command.

sudo keytool -importcert -alias “aws2” -file ~/Desktop/*aws.crt -keystore  /Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Answer (score -1):

I solved it for **Intellij Idea**
I facing this problem  Althouh , I change a lot of place to resolve problem.I found a solution for me .Right click your project ,You will see **Maven** ,after that press **Generate Sources And Update Folders** and **ReImport** [image]

It is done.

Answer (score -1):

You'll get this error when the certificate is newer than your Java version. Using a newer Java version will solve this.

Answer (score -1):

Although I did copy the Certificates to the `cacerts` file The error did not disappear.

The problem was that the **date** on the certificate was **expired**, That's why it returned the error.

I requested a new valid Certificates and the error is now gone.

Comment: How do you do this?

Answer (score -1):

I leave some tips.

1. Use -Dssl.debug=true to check SSL.
2. Check if you are creating a tunnel or try to ignore it

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, (x509CertChain, authType) -> true).build();
            httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
                            .register("https", new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE))
                            .build()
                    )).build();

httpClient.execute(requisicao)
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case (Windows 10, IIS, local development environment (self signed SSL certificate), Apache JMeter). I have to import two certificates to cacerts.
One for my custom host name:
CN = localhostCustom
and second for localhost host name:
CN = localhost

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

**For Linux**

1. Download certificate:

```sh
echo \
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername DOMAIN_NAME -connect DOMAIN_NAME:443 2>/dev/null \
awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/, /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/' >> ~/FILENAME.cer
```

Placeholders:

- `DOMAIN_NAME` - domain name for service
- `FILENAME` - filepath cert

2. Import cert to Java CA certs (**Java 11**):

```sh
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file ~/FILENAME.cer -alias ca_alias -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
```

3. Enter keystore default password `changeit`
4. Trust this certificate: enter `yes`. Output:

```
Certificate was added to keystore
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I solved this problem running from the Android Studio terminal the following command

`./gradlew assemble`

After that the project ran without problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is for Glassfish Server:

Normally Glassfish looks at the cacerts.jks certificate file stored in the `GLASSFISH_SERVER\glassfish\domains\domain1\config` location.You can change this configuration or replace cacerts.jks file with your cacerts file.

There are some default JVM Options which Glassfish is used:

```
 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
 -XX:NewRatio=2
 -XX:MaxPermSize=192m
 -Xmx512m
 -client
 -javaagent:C:/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
 -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
 -Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
 -Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
```

Answer (score -1):

if you're using ubuntu/linux system run the below command in terminal.

**cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates**

**cp /location ofthe file/----.crt .** (copy the crt file in this /usr/local/share/ca-certificates)

**sudo update-ca-certificates**

Answer (score -1):

The trusted certificate are stored in at key tool . When any website trusted certificates are not added in key tools this error occurs. In addition to above answer please refer

[Facing PKIX path building failed exception in selenium broken link script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72859703/facing-pkix-path-building-failed-exception-in-selenium-broken-link-script/72862934#72862934)

Answer (score -1):

- change JDK version from older jdk1.8.0_90 version to some latest version jdk1.8.0_239
- As mentioned in above answers import certificates to keystore
- Add keystore properties to gradle.properties file in java/react native android based projects

> systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C://Program
> Files//AdoptOpenJDK//jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot//jre//lib//security//cacerts
>
> systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit

Answer (score -1):

Please select the root certificate. By default browsers select the child certificate which may not resolve the issue. See this thread for more details: [unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74799868/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target)

Answer (score -2):

i have the same problem on ubuntu 15.10. Please try download plugin locally e.g. https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf/archive/master.zip and install with this command:

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install file:/home/dev/Downloads/elasticsearch-kopf-master.zip
```

Path maybe different depending on your environment.

Regards.

Answer (score -2):

### Error

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'uy-android-pagos'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.goo  gle.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.goo  gle.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://depdes.artifactory.prod.cloud.ihf/artifactory/itau-oq6-frameworks-maven/com/goo%20%20gle/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.1.0/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://depdes.artifactory.prod.cloud.ihf/artifactory/itau-oq6-frameworks-maven/com/goo%20%20gle/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.1.0/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

---

### Solution

Keep in mind that there are many possible causes that generate this error, in my case I fixed it in the following way:

1. Sync Project with Gradle Files
2. Check the error `Could not resolve com.goo  gle.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.0.`
3. Change in `build.gradle (:project)` from `com.goo  gle.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.0` to `com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.0` (note the whitespaces)

Any errors in the dependency classpaths generate this type of exception. Check the gradle of the commit that generates the issue.

GL

Answer (score -2):

If you encountered this error in an IDE such as `Spring Tools Suite` or `Eclipse`, first try using the `HTTP` version of your **URL** instead of `HTTPS`.

I was encountering this error when I was trying to add `SonarQube` link to `Spring Tools Suite`. I replaced my **URL** with:

```
http://sonarqube...
```

instead of

```
https://sonarqube...
```

I have successfully connected `SonarQube`.

I hope it will be helpful for those who are looking for an answer to this question like me.