# Where to find STS.ini file?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to increase the heap stack for STS suite in MAC OSX , but not able to find the sts.ini file to change it, according to this link

http://blog.yohanliyanage.com/2012/11/sts-in-os-x-wheres-the-eclipsests-ini/

it should be in the following folder along with STS.exe file but it is not present and it is not hidden also. Could any one help me in this? Thanks in advance for any help.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this build is based on Eclipse 4.5 the ini file will be in the 'Contents/Eclipse' folder of the package.

Comment: Thanks Greg. File is in contents/eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

I think for newer version (on STS 4.5.1 at least) it is renamed to **SpringToolSuite4.ini**.

You should probably be able to add your configuration opening the file with an editor like Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to locate the STS `.ini` file in Mac is as follows:

Go to **Finder** ➡️ Click **Applications** ➡️ Locate and right-click STS App ➡️ Click **Show Package Contents** ➡️ Navigate to `Contents/Eclipse` where you can find the `.ini` file (e.g. in STS 4, it is `SpringToolSuite4.ini`).

[image]