# Import Windows certificates to Java

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, truststore

I have a java server that is trying to connect to an external Ldap server through SSL (as a client in order to perform queries).

I'm having trouble connecting since the certificate they send me upon connecting is trusted only in my local windows Truststore but is not present in java truststore (cacerts).

Is there a way to tell Java to trust any certificate that windows would have trust?

Or, alternatively, is there a way to import all trusted certificates from windows truststore to Java's cacerts?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell Java to trust any certificate that windows would have trust?

Please check @synoly's answer

The JVM default is located at `jre/lib/security/cacerts`. You can set also your own truststore:

```
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", path_to_your_trustore_jks_file);
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
```

> is there a way to import all trusted certificates from windows truststore to Java's cacerts?

There is no any automatic process, but you could build a program to extract trusted authorities from windows certificate store and import into a truststore configured to use in your application (modifying cacerts is not recommended)

```
//Read Windows truststore
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
ks.load(null, null) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
(1) So is it possible using the snippet you provided to add all the certificates from windows keystore into Java truststore IN Runtime? (I'm thinking about doing it when my java server starts)
(2) Why isn't it recommended to modify cacerts?

Comment: 1) Yes, it is possible, but the changes will be available  depending on when and how is loaded the trustore

Comment: 2) Because cacerts will change between JVM distributions. If the system administrator install a new JVM you will lost all changes.

Answer (score 50):

### Solution

On Windows, set the following JVM properties:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

I’ve successfully tested this with Java 7, which runs on a 64-bit Windows installation which trusts a self-signed CA.

### Configuring the security provider

If the above solution works for you (it should), you may skip this section. Otherwise, check the setup of your [Java Cryptography Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Cryptography_Extension) (JCE), which is [bundled with modern JDKs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html). Your JDK installation should have a property file which contains a list of security providers. The location of that file may vary with Java versions; mine is located at `"%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\java.security"`. Inside that file, locate a set of properties whose names begin with `security.provider`. One of those entries should be set to `sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI`.

### Example

To set the properties at runtime, use the following Java code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "NUL");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "Windows-ROOT");
```

### Explanation

#### javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType

On Windows, Java ships with [SunMSCAPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI), a security provider which is actually [a wrapper around the Windows CAPI.](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1452337547-Different-types-of-keystore-in-Java----Windows-MY)

Setting the `javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType` property to `Windows-ROOT` instructs Java to refer to the native Windows ROOT keystore for trusted certificates, which includes root CAs. (Similarly, setting `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType` to `Windows-MY` tells Java to refer to the native Windows MY keystore for user-specific certificates and their corresponding keys).

#### javax.net.ssl.trustStore

If the `javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType` property is set to `Windows-ROOT`, one would expect that the value of `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` is ignored, and that it can be set to e. g. `NONE`.

One common workaround for this issue is to set `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` to `NONE`, and then creating a dummy file whose file name is `NONE`. If you find yourself affected by this quirk, try setting `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` to `NUL` so you won’t have to create any dummy files.

Comment: Very new answer, but tested and approved for my use case (Intellij behind an HTTPS corporate proxy)

Comment: Are you sure that the link on "Some users report that this approach doesn’t work for them though." is correct?

Comment: @palacsint Strange. I remember double-checking the link when I wrote my answer but of course you’re right, it seems to be completely unrelated. I guess I’ll remove it from the answer.

Comment: Set the windows system environment variable JAVA_OPTS to "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT" and then this will take effect for all JVMs you start.

Comment: Where does one navigate to to actually set these properties?

Comment: @MaxCascone This answer has a section named _Example._ Does that help?