# How to use ssl certificates in Java on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, ssl-certificate

I found this question: [Import Windows certificates to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257366/import-windows-certificates-to-java/49011158#49011158), which had the answer for a Windows machine.  I have been unable to find the equivalent to `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT` for MacOS.

Comment: Does it help? https://blog.alwold.com/2011/06/30/how-to-trust-a-certificate-in-java-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't appear to help. Maven is still unable to find the cert.

Comment: I generally do not specify type when setting up trust locally (i.e. on my Mac), usually I only have to specify `javax.net.ssl.trustStore=<fully qualified path>`. Are you creating a specific type of certificate?

Comment: I apparently already have the correct certificate, as I can browse to the repo using a web browser.  However, Maven is unable to find it.  @JacobBlanton, is the fully qualified path to cacerts, or something else?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The file in my case is an organization's root certificate in `.jks` format.

Comment: Since you mentioned maven it would be better to add that information on your question. There is nothing mentioning it nor the appropriated tag. An improvement would be add something like "I'm trying to build a maven project using a certificate bla bla bla" and also show the commands you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jacob Blanton provided the solution in his comment, above.  By adding `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to cacerts>` to MAVEN_OPTS in my .bash_profile, both standalone Maven and Maven in Eclipse were able to access the repo as needed [after I installed the cert to cacerts using the instructions Jorge Campos linked to in his comment, found here https://blog.alwold.com/2011/06/30/how-to-trust-a-certificate-in-java-on-mac-os-x/ ]

Answer (score 6):

On OSX you can set `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=KeychainStore` to use the OSX keychain for trusted certificates; which is part of the [Apple JCA Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#Apple).

Comment: This solved it for me on macOS Ventura

Answer (score -1):

```
I am using version 10.14.1 (Mojave).
```

1. The path java in my case was: 
   *"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home"*
2. In my **~/.bash_profile** I put this line:
   **export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home"**
3. after that I typed **source ˜/.bash_profile**
4. type echo echo **$JAVA_HOME**
5. Check the configuration typing **$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version**

   - You should see something like that:
     java version "1.8.0_211"
     Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
     Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)