# TrustManagerFactory - Ignore certificate check

Tags: java, azure, ssl

I am using a library to connect to Azure and it uses okhttp3 to handle connections.
There is a part of this library that calls **okhttp3.internal.Util#platformTrustManager**:

```java
 public static X509TrustManager platformTrustManager() {
        try {
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore)null);
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
            if (trustManagers.length == 1 && trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                return (X509TrustManager)trustManagers[0];
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
            }
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException var2) {
            throw assertionError("No System TLS", var2);
        }
    }
```

And the **javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory#getInstance(java.lang.String)**:

```java
public static final TrustManagerFactory getInstance(String var0) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Instance var1 = GetInstance.getInstance("TrustManagerFactory", TrustManagerFactorySpi.class, var0);
        return new TrustManagerFactory((TrustManagerFactorySpi)var1.impl, var1.provider, var0);
    }
```

For some reason, I am getting **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:320)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:284)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:258)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.rest.retry.RetryHandler.intercept(RetryHandler.java:75)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.rest.interceptors.CustomHeadersInterceptor.intercept(CustomHeadersInterceptor.java:140)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.rest.interceptors.UserAgentInterceptor.intercept(UserAgentInterceptor.java:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AzureTokenCredentialsInterceptor.intercept(AzureTokenCredentialsInterceptor.java:40)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.utils.ResourceManagerThrottlingInterceptor.intercept(ResourceManagerThrottlingInterceptor.java:54)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.utils.ProviderRegistrationInterceptor.intercept(ProviderRegistrationInterceptor.java:40)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.rest.interceptors.BaseUrlHandler.intercept(BaseUrlHandler.java:43)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.microsoft.rest.interceptors.RequestIdHeaderInterceptor.intercept(RequestIdHeaderInterceptor.java:29)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:186)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:40)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390)
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443)
    ... 35 more
```

The certificates are validated at **sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker#serverCertificate**:

```java
 ((X509ExtendedTrustManager)var6).checkServerTrusted((X509Certificate[])var2.clone(), var4, this.conn);
```

It's a real valid certificate but the error persists.

I am not sure how to fix this. I wanted to disable the certificate validation altogether but I also can't seem to find a way to do it in this setup.

Why would a valid certificate throw this error?

How can I "install" this certificate (I can only get it as a text, by debugging), or disable the validation?

Also, I am running this on Windows.

Comment: How are you passing certificates to the code for validation?

Comment: I am not. I mean,  trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore)null); loads 94 certificates from somewhere, but I believe it's missing something.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-0ACD9274-607C-49BE-AED9-BEE2B4F2BEF2 describes the default truststore, especially the 4th 5th and 7th paragraphs. You can either look at the file yourself, or see what is being loaded by tracing https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-31B7E142-B874-46E9-8DD0-4E18EC0EB2CF You can get a copy of the server's cert _chain_ (almost never just one cert) with `keytool -printcert -sslserver $host[:$port] -rfc`

Comment: So there are couple of things what you could do. Include the Azure certificate to the cacert of the jdk/jre. I would recommend to use [keystore explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) Or what you also can do is try to provide a custom okhttp which you can configure with a custom sslcontext. You can achieve that with the following code:

SSLContext sslcontext = ...;
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
    .build();

Comment: Whatever your problem is, "I wanted to disable the certificate validation" is not the correct solution for it. It means you void almost all usefulness of TLS, and you are as well as using plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Synoli's answer and great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011158/1031162) I managed to load the correct Windows certificate store with:

```java
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "NUL");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "Windows-ROOT");
```

I am not sure how the certificates are kept and separated in Windows, but without this fix a lot of certificates were loaded but the ones I needed.